# create linked server in azure sql database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, linked-server

Want to create linked server in azure sql.  I want to use local DB views in sql azure using linked server. Is it possible or is there any alternate way.  All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features ; TL;DR no linked servers

Comment: linked or replicated?

Answer (score 7):

yes you can create linked servers in SQLAZURE...Assuming you have local on premises server A and database in azure say AZ_b..you can create a linked server for azure on your local on premise instance...

since you want to do this `I want to use local DB views in sql azure using linked server.`  after creating linked server **you need to run queries from server A which is your local onpremises server** and this is the only way name resolution of linked server can happen and you can't do the other way

below are the steps

```
-- Supporse your database on Azure is named 'Azure_Test_DB' 
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
@server='myLinkedAzureServer', -- specify the name of the linked server   
@srvproduct='',        
@provider='sqlncli', 
@datasrc='azure-test-db.database.windows.net',   -- add here your server name   
@location='',   
@provstr='',   
--------Change it by your need ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
@catalog='Azure_Test_DB'  -- specify the name of database on your Azure DB you want to link 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

-- Configure credentials for Azure linked server 
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
@rmtsrvname = 'myLinkedAzureServer',   
@useself = 'false',   
--------Change it by your need ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
@rmtuser = 'yourLoginName',   -- add here your login on Azure DB   
@rmtpassword = 'yourPassword' -- add here your password on Azure DB   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

-- Configure options for Azure linked server 
EXEC sp_serveroption 'myLinkedAzureServer', 'rpc out', true;   


-- Now you can query the data using 4-part names   
select * from myLinkedAzureServer.[Azure_Test_DB].[dbo].[Students];
```

once you create  linked server , you can connect to server A and can run below queries

```
select * from 
myLinkedAzureServer.[Azure_Test_DB].[dbo].[Students] az
join
localdb.dbo.table1 tbl
on tbl.somecol=az.somecol
```

**References:**
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-create-linked-cb98fa7d
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3630/connect-an-azure-sql-database-to-an-onpremises-sql-server/

The above steps works for most of machines..incase it doesn't work, you need to setup a ODBC DSN by following the steps here..

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/03/07/linked-servers-to-sql-azure/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a linked server in Azure SQL Database.

Microsoft does have a preview available of a new Instance as a Service offering that will allow you to perform cross database queries. It may also allow for linked servers. It's not yet widely available.

Now, you can use [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started) to set up something pretty similar. Here's a [blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/) I wrote on it. However, it's not the same as a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to the limitation of linked servers not available on SQL Azure databases, you can replicate objects from on-premises SQL Server databases to SQL Azure or use SQL Data Sync to sync data between on-premises SQL Server and a SQL Azure server.

Hope this helps.